# Strange behaviour of a sql statement with 'case'

Tags: sql, oracle, switch-statement, case

I am trying to create an SQL report. This is the select statement:

```
  select
  -- ticket id
  '<tr align=left valign=top><td width=95>'||maspid||'</td>'||

  -- priority
  case when instr(masfld017, '<|lang' ) = 0 then
        '<td width=90>'||masfld017
  else
        '<td width=90>'||substr( masfld017, 1 , instrb(masfld017, '<|lang') - 1)
  end||'</td>'||

  -- customer
  '<td width=150>'||masfld007||'</td>'||

  -- status
    '<td width=100>'||decode(masfld104, '0', 'Collected',
          '1', 'Postponed',
          '2', 'Accepted',
          '3', 'in Progress',
          '5', 'Work Around',
          '7', 'Solved',
          '8', 'Closed')||'</td>'||

  -- subject
  '<td width=400>'||masfld001||'</td>'||

  -- full name
  '<td width=100>' || replace(replace(masfld037, '<||>'), '</||>')||'</td>'||

  -- creation date
  '<td width=150>'||to_char(to_date(masfld022, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MI'), 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MM')||'</td>'||

  -- target date
  '<td width=150>'||to_char(to_date(masfld023, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MI'), 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MM')||'</td>'||

  -- ticket type
  '<td width=180>'||decode(masfld040, '9', 'HUS',
        '8', 'Project',
        '7', 'Enhancement',
        '6', 'Complaint',
        '5', 'Change Request',
        '4', 'Bug (Do not use)',
        '3', 'Support',
        '2', 'Service Request',
        '1', 'Incident (Problem)',
        null, 'N/A')||'</td></tr>'
from
        k2h.tmaster01 tm inner join k2h.tprofile tp on replace(replace(tm.masfld035, '<||>'), '</||>') = tp.propid
where
        masfld024 is null and
        masfld082 = '&REGION' 

order by case masfld017
        when 'Emergency'         then 1 
        when 'Critical'          then 2
        when 'High'              then 3
        when 'Major Problem'     then 4
        when 'Major defect'      then 5
        when 'Semi-major defect' then 6
        when 'Medium'            then 7
        when 'Minor Problem'     then 8
        when 'Low'               then 9
        end;
```

If I run it directly with sqldeveloper, I get a result list. If the report is started by crontab, it fails with this error message:

```
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "case when ..." - rest of line ignored. SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "'
```

Seems like the case `command` is not recognized, but why?

Comment: Please, post all sql statement.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth That wasn't in the originally posted code, which only included the `order by case...`

Comment: I included the whole statement. But why is it working with sqldeveloper? Yes it is the same statement that is executed.

Comment: What version of Oracle are you running?

Comment: `$ORACLE_HOME  :   /opt/oracle/10.2.0`

Comment: This query is ok. It has not any issue.

Comment: You seem to be constructing HTML. It's usually a really bad idea to do it in the database. Do you not have a more suitable language for doing this construction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

is it possible , in crontab, that you're running the SQL direct in the shell
eg

```
sqlplus...<<ESQL
select..
...
order by case end;
```

?
if so please remove the BLANK lines.

otherwise you will get something like:

```
SQL> select
  2    -- ticket id
  3    '<tr align=left valign=top><td width=95>'||maspid||'</td>'||
  4
SQL>   -- priority
SQL>   case when instr(masfld017, '<|lang' ) = 0 then
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "case when ..." - rest of line ignored.
```

Comment: Thank you very much, removing the blank lines worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: I had the same issue. Everything ran in SQL Developer, but failed in sqlplus. Removing blank lines and indents solved the issue. My code doesn't look pretty, but it runs now.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest removing the spaces and possibly even the comments from your SQL command and try that. SQL*Plus is picky about spaces embedded in commands.  I've even had problems with double-dash comments and SQL*Plus scripts. I think it's the spaces, but if it's the comments, use the `/* ... */` style of comment.

Comment: Correct answer but @DanzzaL was faster.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the parser seems to be interpreting the `case` statement as a PLSQL `case` statement, rather than a `SELECT` case statement.  That is, it isn't seeing the expression as part of a column but as part of a PLSQL statement.  The "SP" error messages refer to SQL-Plus rather than to the language itself.

My guess is that something above the `select` statement is confusing the script.